# Como guardo la informacion en el JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Necesito guardar mi informacion de un formulario en el localstorage, estuve probando pero no me salio nada. Lo unico que hice lo borre porque no funcionaba. La idea es que el usuario ponga los datos y que se guarden por si quiere volver a comprar. Lo unico que hice fue un array llamado prueba para ir subiendo todo ahi.

```
const nombreyApellido = document.getElementById('nombreyApellido')
const tel = document.getElementById('tel')
const gmail = document.getElementById('gmail')
const numeroTarjeta = document.getElementById('numeroTarjeta')
const cvc = document.getElementById('cvc')
const formCompra = document.getElementById('formCompra')
const advertencia = document.getElementById('warning')
const completado = document.getElementById('completado')

const prueba = []

if (formCompra) {
formCompra.addEventListener("submit", e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    let warning = ""
    let entrar = false
    let validaremail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
    if (nombreyApellido.value.length <= 2) {
        warning += 'El nombre y apellido es muy corto <br>'
        entrar = true
    }
    if (tel.value.length <= 7) {
        warning += 'El telefono es muy corto <br>'
        entrar = true
    }
    if (!validaremail.test(gmail.value)) {
        warning += 'El email no es valido <br>'
        entrar = true
    }
    if (numeroTarjeta.value.length <= 10) {
        warning += 'El número de tarjeta es muy corto <br>'
        entrar = true
    }
    if (cvc.value.length <= 2 || cvc.length >= 4) {
        warning += 'El cvc no es correcto <br>'
        entrar = true
    }
    if (entrar) {
        advertencia.innerHTML = warning 
    }else{
        completado.innerHTML = 'Enviado'
    }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `prueba` te recomiendo que sea un objecto JSON. Para asignar los valores al objeto solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Primer método
const prueba = {};
prueba.nombreyApellido = nombreyApellido;
prueba.tel = tel;
prueba.numeroTarjeta = numeroTarjeta;
prueba.cvc = cvc;

// Segundo método
const prueba = {
   nombreyApellido,
   tel,
   numeroTarjeta,
   cvc
}
```

y así con todos los datos que quieras guardar. Luego tienes que convertir el objecto en un string:

```
const pruebaStr = JSON.stringify(prueba);
```

Ahora solo queda guardarlo en localStorage:

```
//Guardar:
localStorage.setItem("datos", pruebaStr)

//leer:
let datosString = localStorage.getItem("datos"); //Devuelve el string guardado anteriormente
let datos = JSON.parse(datosString); //Convertir el string guardado en objeto
```

Si algo no ha quedado claro, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Disculpa poruqe me salta un error, me dice que "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse

Que significaria eso? Hay algo que estoy poniendo mal?

Comment: Al parecer tiene un error en esta línea, está tratando de guardar el objeto "prueba". 

//Guardar:
localStorage.setItem("datos", prueba)

y se debe guardar la variable "pruebaStr" quedando de la siguiente manera:

//Guardar:
localStorage.setItem("datos", pruebaStr);

espero con eso resuelvas el error.

Comment: Ya corregí el error que dijo @Diego Dam